# self.navigationController is nil after adding subview

Tags: iphone, subview, navigationcontroller

here is my productscontroller.h

```
ProductListViewController *productListViewController;
ProductGridViewController *productGridViewController;
UIButton *flipIndicatorButton;
```

and i am adding list and gridview as a subview like this in my implementation

```
ProductListViewController *listController = [[ProductListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductListView" bundle:nil];
self.productListViewController = listController;
self.productListViewController.CurrentSale = CurrentSale;
[self.view insertSubview:listController.view atIndex:0];
```

but in when i tried to push detailview  controller from ProductListViewController.m like this

```
ProductDetailViewController *productDetailViewController = [[ProductDetailViewController alloc] init];

productDetailViewController.productIndexPath = indexPath;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:productDetailViewController animated:YES];
```

it just does not work, then i check [self.navigationController] , it was nil, 
now how to deal with this problem. i am ready to give some more code and detail to make more clear. thanks

Comment: if you're using a navigation controller, why are you inserting a subview instead of pushing views to the controller?

also, is the navigation controller nil before you insert the subview as well?

Comment: thanks Oren, not its not nil,let me tell how my app structure.
TabBarController
-NavigationControler
--TableViewController
---ProductController(self.navigationControll is not  null here)
----ListViewController(self.navigationControll is nil)
----GridViewControler(self.navigationControll is nil)

ihope this make picture clear.

Comment: and i am adding flip view button as right button item, that gets added. and i can flip view, but i cant push another view control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found workaround for this problem.
now what i am doing is i am passing ref of parent controller in this case ProductsController and written method to push next view. following this now i am calling parent method to push next view like this
[parent pushNextview];
so far it works fine, hope this is good way of doing what i wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you creating the Navigation Controller? At some point (probably in your App Delegate) you have to have something like this:

```
ProductsController *productsController = // create ProductsController
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:productsController];
```

And then add the navController's view as a subview to your window.

The other thing is that you appear to be using too many View Controllers for one screen. Apple recommends only one per screen.

Comment: thanks bpapa, i am using only one Controller per screen, its just that i cant make view hierarchy in here.
i have tabbar, and i have make first tabbar as Navigation in my Mainwindow.xib, and i am creating ProductController in BrandList controller that is my first screen , not app delegate. is this clear.if not let me know how i can make it more clear.

Comment: i follow this example for create subviews(i did same thing with minor change) http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TheElements/index.html , hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently! I "poped" ([self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]) the viewController in the viewWillAppear: method of the viewcontroller. So I just removed this code and inserted the same code in the viewDidAppear: method and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue yesterday:

`Tab Bar View - Table View - View`

In the table view controller, I wanted to push the "detail view" controller, but `[self navigationController]`  was `nil` here.  The solution was to go to this arrangement:

`Tab Bar View - Navigation View - Table View - View`

With the additional navigation controller, `[self navigationController]` now worked in the table view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out why the navigationController is always nil.  Your whole series of views should be contained in a UINavigationController.  This means that the first view in your hierarchy will have to be your rootViewController.  bpapas code should work.